# margin-top:percentage; not bound to parent height?

Tags: css, height, margin

I have a `<div>` that's `100px` tall (for demonstration purposes).
Inside that `<div>` is another that's `60%` tall with a `margin-top` of `20%`.
I expect the result to be a `60px` tall `<div>` with a `margin-top` of `20px`.

Unfortunately, that isn't the case and I can't figure this one out.

Here's the CSS:

```
html, body {
     min-height:100%;
}
div#one {
     height:100px;
}
div#two {
    background:red;
    height:60%;
    margin-top:20%;
    margin-bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            <div id="two">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HpaQp/) to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage values for the margin/padding properties are always relative to the containing block's width, even in the case of `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` - from the [2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties):

> **Margin**
>
> **`<percentage>`:**   The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. **Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.** If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LE4ee/1/) using a `relative` position.

```
div#one {
    background-color:green;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
}

div#two {
    float: left;
    position: realtive;
    background:red;
    height:60%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}
```

Comment: Tried in Chrome and Safari, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: `webkit-flex;` still doesn't answer the question. `div#two` should have a `20%` top margin.

Comment: Updated the Fiddle using `position: relative` and `float: left`. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/HpaQp/5/

---

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div#one {
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100px;
}

div#one {
    height: 100px;
}

div#two {
    background: red;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HpaQp/1/

Comment: 100px was just for the example, I need to use percentages.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the specs at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-top you will notice

> Percentages:      refer to width of containing block

so in your case 20% applied to `#two` means 20% of the width of `#one`